# How to print out all keys in a Dictionary with more than just 1 value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I want to  print out all the available keys in the dictionary.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1}

print(d.keys())

>>> dict_keys(['a', 'c', 'o', 'r', 't'])
```

but I want to print out all the keys `a, c, o, r, r, t` , 
because there are 2 r 
not only `a, c, o, r, t`

Comment: To prevent confusion: there are _not_ two `r`s in `d`; `"r"` is associated with the value `2`. It could be associated with any other value, including text or other objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to print acorrt :

```
for key, value in d.items() :
    for x in range (0, value):
        print(key)
```

Not sure why you would want to do that, though. As the commenter above mentioned, a key is unique, it's just the value that changes.

Answer (score 1):

a variant using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

d = {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1}
lst = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(letter, times) 
           for letter, times in d.items()))
print(lst)  # ['r', 'r', 't', 'a', 'c', 'o']
```

every key (`letter`) in the dict is [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)ed as many times as the value (`times`) suggests; the results are [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)ed together and used in the list constructor.

or without `repeat` (instead with `times * [letter]`):

```
from itertools import chain

lst = list(chain.from_iterable(times * [letter] for letter, times in d.items()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And the explanation.  It looks very intimidating, but your explanation really help me to understand what the coding meant.

Comment: the intimidation will decrease the more you code stuff! [`chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) is a standard way to flatten nested lists. and `itertools` is a very valuable toolset to know a bit about. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, someone posted an answer and I was able to tweek it. It's is for a game and we have to put out all available letters.

```
for k,v in d.items():   
    print(k, end = " ")
    if v > 1:
        print(k, end=" ")
```

Thank you so much for the help!!! And sharing your knowledge